# text coming out from div i just need only title and data should increase their font size

Tags: angularjs

[image]I just need ** only data and title must be increase their font size** when I changed the switch statement but i dont want to increase size of font size of right corner how can i do that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    ***emphasized text***
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-gridster.min.css"></link>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="wid.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body   ng-controller="myController" >
      <div gridster  ng-controller="myCtrl"  > 
        <ul>
          <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in Items">
            <div my-widget ></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <select ng-model="fontStyle" ng-change="style()">
        <option value="larger">larger</option> 
        <option value="middle">middle</option>
        <option value="small">small</option>
     </select>
   </body>

</html>
```

my `script` goes here which contains the `controller` as well as `directive`.

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['gridster'])
app.controller('myController',function($scope){

  $scope.Items = [
    { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj:{data:54565463,right:67566,title:'Headers'}},
    { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj: {data:65476756,right:12344,title:"Income"}}]



  $scope.style = function() {   
    style = $scope.fontStyle;

    switch (style) {
      case 'larger':
        $scope.myStyle = {      
          "font-size": "2.3em",
        }

        break;     
      case 'middle':

        $scope.myStyle = {            
          "font-size": "2.0em"
        }
        break;
      case 'small':

        $scope.myStyle = {            
          "font-size": "1.3em",
        }      
        break;     
      default:
        alert('/#larger');     
    }   
  }
});

 app.directive('myWidget',function(){

        return{

            restrict:"EA",
            scope:{ 
            title:'@',
            data:'=',
            },
            templateUrl:'spare.html',
            }

        });
```

and my `spare html` is below -

```
<span ng-controller="myController" >
  <div class="panel-body"  >
    <h1  class="title" >{{data.title}}</h1>
    <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>{{data.data}}
  </h1></div>
  <p id="rightcorner"><i class="fa fa-level-up"></i>{{data.right}} 
  </p>
</span>
```

Comment: any ideas please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-style` for elements that you want assign style dynamically. 
See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) for details and examples.

If you want to add style which is stored in `$scope.myStyle` it goes like that:

```
<div ng-style="myStyle">...</div>
```

Complete example:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
    myStyle current value: {{myStyle}}
    <div ng-style="myStyle">
      element with style
    </div>
    <button ng-click=changeStyle()>
        Change style
    </button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.myStyle = {
    color: 'red'
  };

  $scope.changeStyle = function() {
    $scope.myStyle = {
      color: 'blue'
    };
  }
});
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tanssnrL/3/)

Comment: thanks @ lukasz .i m unable to apply can u provide me any fiddles

Comment: lemme check  @lukasz

Comment: Are you sure, that `$scope.myStyle` has correct value? You can temporary add `{{myStyle}}` to html to be sure.

Comment: yea thats fine with ng-click but i  want that with switch   statement

Comment: ya i will make fiddle and i will inform u

Comment: @lukasaz i m unable to add local source files in fiddle how can i do that

Comment: Try to reproduce your problem without adding source files. If you need to add data you can store some (as little as it's needed to present problem) in variable.

Comment: can u give me u r mail id i will send my code @Lukasz

Comment: I would prefer to solve problem here. So, which part exactly doesn't work correctly? Does function style work as you expect?

Comment: yea  style perfectly but  i had to do that with  switch statement as u see in my code above when  i click larger button the text  present at right corner should not  change  its font style it has to be same as constant the switch logic should not apply to the right corner text

Comment: so add ng-style="myStyle" to html element for which you want change stale

Comment: <span ng-controller="myCtrl" >
<div class="panel-body">
<h1  class="title" ng-style="myStyle">{{data.title}}</h1>
<i class="fa fa-dollar"  ng-style="myStyle"></i>{{data.data}}
</div>
 <p id="rightcorner"><i class="fa fa-level-up"></i>{{data.right}} 
 </p>
 </span>  yea but it is still is not working @lukasz

Comment: and what is the effect?

Comment: there is no change it has same as above screen shot which i had provided

Comment: add {{myStyle}} somewher in html to make sure that this variable has value you expect

Comment: i had added but there is no change in it

Comment: you mean, that value of myStyle does not change? That means that function style doesn't do what it should do, right?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tanssnrL/12/ your function style works fine. Select as well (everything in this fiddle works as I expect).

Comment: so we need to find out why value of myStyle (shown by {{myStyle}}) is not correct, right?

Comment: ya function is working the thing i need is only title name and value should change its is font not the value present at an right corner

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tanssnrL/15/ i just made some changes the value which is present at right corner should not change in my case  in your  case i had just closed div after the value  in my case it is different  hope u got my question

Comment: great, let me check

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tanssnrL/17/ It's about closing element. In fiddle you sent rightcorner was inside element with ng-style, that's why it's style was affected.

Comment: ya thats correct  . in my case  the scenario is different   i know  i had closed the ng-style  after the div  but in my case scenario is different

Comment: You need to identify what css rules are applied for right corner element. Propably applied rules are inherited from element in which my-widget is placed.

Comment: oh thanks now what i need is can i pass ngstyle in object which i had provided in controller  so that  font size in one div must be differ with another which i want to change font size dynamically